# Javascript string utf-8

Tags: utf-8, javascript

Dear Javascript experts

I was wondering if there was a way of determining wether or not a javascript string is in utf-8?
So i could do something like this:

```
if(myString == checkutf8())
{ 
  // do something
}
```

Is there any library out there that can do such things?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `a javascript string is in utf-8` That is meaningless.  UTF8 is a way to encode strings into bytes.

Comment: But i have a function which takes a utf-16 string as a parameter and than converts it to utf-8. So i am trying to filter out the strings that are already in utf-8 before they get converted by the function so that symbols don't go lostn

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense.  (unless you're treating a string as a byte array and storing raw UTF-8 bytes, in which case it's impossible)

Comment: Ok, i guess that's what i'm looking for then. What would be the best way to convert my javascript array to a byte array?

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To treat a js string as a byte array and compare that byte array to other byte arrays.